# How are singleton methods useful?

Tags: ruby, singleton

I am pretty new to Ruby and have learned it syntax along with singleton methods.  I understand how to create and use them.  But why use them?

Can someone give me a few real world cases where using singleton methods are helpful?

Thank You

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/86169

Comment: @Damieh This question is not about the singleton pattern, but about singleton methods as they exist in Ruby. Singleton methods do not violate OOP at all in Ruby.

Comment: @Damieh Singleton concept does not go against OOP. There are prototype based OOP and class based OOP. Both are OOP, and prototype based OOP only have singletons.

Comment: I use Singleton when I feel those methods would be used in several places in my application and I feel lazy calling the new constructor, however a benchmark of modules and Singleton method/Singleton classes shows modules are accessed faster than Singletons however the difference is negligible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to do some debugging? Say you have a collection of objects, and you know one of them acts up while being iterated over alongside it's siblings... so you modify a problematic method to wrap it in some logging / tracing code that saves you having to read pages of logging statements for the 100 other items.

That's at least one contrived example I can think of.

Comment: thanks.. i agree.  good example.

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/singletonmethods.html
- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/86169 ;
- http://ola-bini.blogspot.com/2006/09/ruby-singleton-class.html

Singleton methods: It is often useful to be able to define special behavior for an individual object.

Answer (score 1):

At least, you need a constructor, which has to be a singleton method on the class. Without constructors, you would not even have instances (other than by always creating instances from literals). And the way you would like to construct an instance should not be limited to one way. For example, `Time` has the constructors `now`, `at`, `utc`, `gm`, etc.

Comment: You left out the ubiquitous `new` singleton method on Class.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Actually, `new` usually is an instance method of `Class`. Only in special circumstances is it overridden.

Comment: You mean class methods, not singleton methods, right? Or are these the same as singleton methods on a class?

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right. I shouldn't type things late at night `:P`.

Comment: @padde Class methods are singleton methods defined on an instance of a Class class or instance methods defined on Class.